# Unable to connect ,can’t establish a connection to the server

Tags: php, nginx, http-status-code-404, ubuntu-server

I understand the question has been asked for a number of times,unfortunately in my scenario I don't seem to get where the issue is.

After setting up a site using nginx with these configurations '

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name  xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.co.zw;
root   /var/www/xxxxxx;
index  index.php;

access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;

client_max_body_size 100M;

autoindex off;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
     include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
     fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
     include fastcgi_params;
}
}'
```

The .htacess file in the public (lavarel site)has these configuration '

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
       Options -MultiViews
  </IfModule>

  RewriteEngine On

  # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

  # Handle Front Controller...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
  </IfModule>'
```

And the error I am getting is "The requested URL can not be retrieved.Unable to connect to remote server".When I try to run it on localhost it's still through the same error.

I tried running these commands but it hasn't been fruitful '

```
  sudo a2enmod rewrite
  sudo a2ensite xxxxxx.conf
  sudo systemctl restart nginx'
```

The error log is blank and here is the access log '

```
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Dec/2019:08:00:46 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200              396 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Dec/2019:08:00:47 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 134 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Dec/2019:08:16:36 +0000] "GET /phpinfo.php  HTTP/1.1" 200       21 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101     Firefox/71.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Dec/2019:08:17:43 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-"     "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0"'
```

Please help.

Comment: can you check ngix server error log ?if find post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the access.log and error.log of nginx to debug this issue.